# Filtering a complicated nested array in Swift 3

Tags: algorithm, swift3

I have a complicated array (tree) like this:

```
[0] code = "pc1"
    children
      [0] code = "gc1"
          children
              [0] code = "cc1"
                  children = nil
              [1] code = "cc2"
                  children = nil
      [1] code = "gc2"
          children = nil
[1] code = "pc2"
    children = nil
```

What I want is to search any node without children. And I want to keep the hierarchy if any children note found. For example, search for "2" will return this:

```
[0] code = "pc1"
    children
      [0] code = "gc1"
          children
              [0] code = "cc2"
                  children = nil
      [1] code = "gc2"
          children = nil
[1] code = "pc2"
    children = nil
```

Search for "p" will return:

```
[0] code = "pc1"
    children
[1] code = "pc2"
    children = nil
```

I tried for quite long time. But failed to find a solution. Any idea? Thanks.

**Edited on 27/8/2017:**

Here is my tree class:

```
class Node {

  var parentCode: String = ""

  weak var parent: Node?
  lazy var children = [Node]()

  init() {}

  func add(node: Node) {
    children.append(code)
    code.parent = self
  }
```

[image]

This will be the result if I want to search for letter **o**.

Comment: Actually this is a question about the tree filtering. I built my tree structure. Any algorithm will be able to do this?